# xml:lang parse in PHP

Tags: php, xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <answer>
    <describe data="aircompany">
      <data>
        <code xml:lang="ru">FW</code>
        <code xml:lang="en">FW</code>
      </data>
      <data>
        <code xml:lang="ru">UT</code>
        <code xml:lang="en">ЮТ</code>
      </data>
    </describe>
  </answer>
```

I need get nodes value, there xml:lang="en". How can do it in PHP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, SimpleXML works but try adding the [xml namespace](http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace) if you run into trouble.

E.g.:

```
<?php
$xmlstr = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<answer xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace">
    <describe data="aircompany">
      <data>
        <code xml:lang="ru">ФВ</code>
        <code xml:lang="en">FW</code>
      </data>
      <data>
        <code xml:lang="ru">УТ</code>
        <code xml:lang="en">UT</code>
      </data>
    </describe>
</answer>
XML;

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);

foreach ($xml->xpath('//data/code[@xml:lang="en"]') as $code) {
    echo $code, '<br/>', PHP_EOL;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 5):

XPath has a special construct for dealing with xml:lang attribute:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($strXML);
$data = $xml->describe->data[0];
$elCode = $data->xpath("code[lang('en')]"); // returns array of SimpleXMLElement
assert(count($elCode)==1);
$code_en = (string) $elCode[0];
```

P.S. greetings to the Sirena ;)

Answer (score 1):

Has been answered before:

```
$dom =new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML( $xml );
$xPath = new DOMXPath( $dom );
$nodes = $xPath->query( '/answer/describe/data/code[@xml:lang = "en"]' );
foreach( $nodes as $node ) {
    echo $node->nodeValue; 
}
```

Alternative without XPath:

```
$dom =new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML ($xml );
foreach( $dom->getElementsByTagName( 'code' ) as $node ) {
    if( $node->getAttribute( 'xml:lang' ) === 'en') {
        echo $node->nodeValue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks.
I use this method:

```
$XMLObj = new SimpleXMLElement($XML);
print_r($XMLObj->xpath('/answer/describe/data/code[@xml:lang = "en"]'));
```

Comment: Good stuff. Welcome to stack :)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [PHP SAX parser decribed here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php).

Comment: Can parse xml:lang, using SimpleXMLElement?