# How to load all xml:lang attributes with SimpleXML

Tags: php, xml, simplexml, lang

How to read ALL atribute `xml:lang` values?
Sometimes I do not know how many languages are defined in XMLs data.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<offer>
  <products>
    <product>
      <description>
        <name xml:lang="eng">English translation</name>
        <name xml:lang="lat">Latvian translation</name>
      </description>
    </product>
    <product>
      <description>
        <name xml:lang="eng">The same English</name>
        <name xml:lang="pol">And Polish language</name>
      </description>
    </product>
  </products>
</offer>
```

I can [xml:lang parse in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3996444/xmllang-parse-in-php) by adding exact language code in xpath

`print_r($xml->xpath('products/product/description/name[@xml:lang = "eng"]'));`

But I need to add all xml:lang atributes values to parsed array.

Can it be done with PHP SimpleXML?

Comment: What I need - to collect `xml:lang` values, e.g. for `xml:lang="cze"` will return `"cze"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about this:

```
$nodes = $xml->xpath('products/product/description/name[@xml:lang]');
```

Will return an array of `<name>`-nodes.

If this is not it, please clarify exactly your desired result.

**EDIT**

try this to get the `xml:lang` attributes only:

```
$langs = $xml->xpath("products/product/description/name[@xml:lang]/@xml:lang");
// $lang is an array of simplexml-elements, transform the values to string like this:
$langs = array_map("strval", $langs);
```

Comment: This will return indexed array `['description']['name'][0] .. [1]` but not value for `xml:lang="cze"`.

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for! Best wishes!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% on SimpleXML sorry, but I know [DomDocument](https://www.php.net/domdocument) can do what you are after. Hopefully this can be of use to you:

```
$xmlstring = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<offer>
  <products>
    <product>
      <description>
        <name xml:lang="eng">English translation</name>
        <name xml:lang="lat">Latvian translation</name>
      </description>
    </product>
    <product>
      <description>
        <name xml:lang="eng">The same English</name>
        <name xml:lang="pol">And Polish language</name>
      </description>
    </product>
  </products>
</offer>';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($xmlstring); //or $dom->load('filename.xml');

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$nodes = $xpath->query('//products/product/description/name');

foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    echo 'Language: ' . $node->getAttribute('xml:lang') . '<br />';
    echo 'Value: ' . $node->nodeValue . '<br /><br />';
}
```

You can assign $node->getAttribute('xml:lang') to a variable and run some checks to see if it matches 'eng' or whatever you need.

I used xpath as you had in your original post, but you can also use $dom->getElementsByTagName('name') and access values and attributes in much the same way.

Comment: Since this returns element nodes, SimpleXML's `->xpath()` method would also work fine, although the namespace handling for the `xml:lang` attribute might be more fiddly.

Comment: I cannot use loadXML, because I have very large XML and loadXML will load it all in memory

Comment: Try calling loadXML with the [LIBXML_PARSEHUGE](http://www.php.net/manual/en/libxml.constants.php) option
`$domDocument->loadXML($xml, LIBXML_PARSEHUGE);`
or if you're loading form a file, use load->('filename.xml')

Comment: I was looking for solution with `SimpleXML`, but with `dom->load('filename.xml')` Your solution also works.

Comment: I should really look into SimpleXML a bit more hehe, glad domdoc could be of use though :)

Answer (score 1):

I found easier way to access namespaced attributes. You could use `$name->attributes("xml", true)` function.

Here is working example:

```
<?php 
  
$xmlString = '
<products> 
  <product>
    <name xml:lang="eng">
      Apples
    </name>
    <name xml:lang="fr">
      Pommes
    </name>
  </product>
  <product>
    <name xml:lang="eng">
      Strawberries
    </name>
    <name xml:lang="fr">
      Fraises
    </name>
  </product>
</products> 
'; 

$xml = new \SimpleXMLElement($xmlString); 

foreach($xml->product as $product) 
{ 
  foreach ($product->name as $name) 
  {
    $attributes = $name->attributes("xml", true);
    // print_r($attributes);

    foreach ($attributes as $attributeName => $attributeValue)
    {
      // echo $attributeName . PHP_EOL;
      // echo $attributeValue . PHP_EOL;

      if ($attributeValue == "eng" && $attributeName == "lang") {
        echo "English: " . trim(((string) $name)) . PHP_EOL;
      }
      if ($attributeValue == "fr" && $attributeName == "lang") {
        echo "French: " . trim(((string) $name)) . PHP_EOL;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Online demo: https://repl.it/repls/LovingFineDaemon

Comment: This feels like an answer to a different question (and in particular [this reference question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44894426/reference-how-do-i-handle-namespaces-tags-and-attributes-with-colon-in-in-si)) since it doesn't show how to fetch all the languages in the document, as asked for.