# JMS Serializer to read xml:lang attribute

Tags: php, xml, jms-serializer

This is related to [xml:lang parse in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3996444/2184166).

We use [JMS serializer](http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/reference/annotations) to create XML requests to and parse XML responses from Sirena-Travel (airticket provider). A whole system of annotated DTOs is built around this serializer, and we're unlikely to change this.

There is a reponse XML we'd like to deserialize (the same as in the above question):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <answer>
    <describe data="aircompany">
      <data>
        <code xml:lang="ru">FW</code>
        <code xml:lang="en">FW</code>
      </data>
      <data>
        <code xml:lang="ru">UT</code>
        <code xml:lang="en">ЮТ</code>
      </data>
    </describe>
  </answer>
```

The question is: How do I specify a property corresponding to `xml:lang` attribute?

This is how classes describing the innermost elements look like:

```
class DescribeData
{
    /**
     * Codes in various languages.
     *
     * @Type("array<DescribeLangElement>")
     * @XmlList(inline = true, entry = "code")
     */
    private $codes = [];

    public function getCode($lang)
    {
        foreach ($this->codes as $code) {
            if ($code->getLang() === $lang) {
                return $code;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}

class DescribeLangElement
{
    /**
     * Element's language code.
     *
     * Either "en" or "ru".
     *
     * @Type("string")
     * @XmlAttribute
     */
    private $lang;

    /**
     * @Type("string")
     * @XmlValue
     */
    private $value;
}
```

Obviously, the serializer does not recognize `xml:lang` attribute as `$lang` property. I tried a couple of approaches:

- Add `@SerializedName("xml:lang")` to `$lang` property.
- Add namespace annotation:

  ```
   @XmlNamespace(uri = "http://example.com/", prefix = "xml")
  ```

  either to the parent node or to the root node, while modifying `@XmlAttribute` annotation on `$lang` property to look like

  ```
   @XmlAttribute(namespace = "http://example.com/")
  ```

Needless to say, no success with either or both of them.

I also have in mind alternate solutions like:

- Preprocess the XML to convert `xml:lang` attribute to `lang`.
- Write a custom deserialization handler to deal with `DescribeLangElement` class.

But those seem like an overkill to me.

Is there a straight-forward way to specify a property for `xml:lang` attribute with JMS serializer annotations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> #### Namespace constraint: Reserved Prefixes and Namespace Names
>
> The prefix **xml** is by definition bound to the namespace name `http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace`. It *may*, but need not, be declared, and *must not* be undeclared or bound to any other namespace name. Other prefixes *must not* be bound to this namespace name, and it *must not* be declared as the default namespace.

*From: http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names11/#xmlReserved*

Therefore the namespace is not `http://example.com/` but `http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace`.