# PHP XMLReader xml:lang

Tags: php, xml

How can I read the xml:lang Value from this xml File???

```html
 <Catalog><Products>
<Product>
<Id>123</Id>
<Name xml:lang="en">name english product</Name>
<Description xml:lang="en">desc xyz</Description>
<Name xml:lang="de">name german</Name>
<Description xml:lang="de">desc germa</Description>
<Image num="1"><Url>pic.jpg</Url></Image>
<Image num="2"><Url>pic2.jpg</Url></Image>
</Product>
<Product>...
```

I want the value of the xml:lang="de" - Tag and the Image-Values. 
Does anybody have an idea???
Thanx :-)

Update: I parse the xml like this, but how do i get this values???

```js
$datei = "test.xml";
$z = new XMLReader;
$z->open($datei);
 
$doc = new DOMDocument;
 
while ($z->read() && $z->name !== 'Product');

$i = 0; while ($z->name === 'Product')
{ $i++;
$node = simplexml_import_dom($doc->importNode($z->expand(), true));

...
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [xml:lang parse in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3996444/xmllang-parse-in-php)

Comment: Du you want the Xpath-Expression for it? Or the php-functions to parse the xml and extract the data?

Comment: i have update the post...the php functions???

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do it.

```
$simpleXml = new SimpleXMLElement(file_get_contents($datei));
foreach ($simpleXml->Products->Product as $product) {
   $name = $product->xpath('Name[@xml:lang="en"]')[0];
   echo $name . "\n";
   foreach($product->Image as $img) {
       echo $img->Url . "\n";
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works great :-) ... is there a way to read the values from the while loop??? something like this??? $node->Name->attributes('@xml:lang="en"]')[0];

Answer (score 0):

xpath use to many resurses. You can scan it, taking needed nodes. In the code you will see how take name and value of nodes and attributes, which have prefix.

```
$simpleXml = new SimpleXMLElement(file_get_contents($datei)));
foreach ($simpleXml->Products->Product as $products)      // list of nodes with same name
   foreach($products as $product) {                       // every node
    if ($product->getName() === 'Image')  {                // for image take child
        echo $product->Url->getName() . " = " . $product->Url ."\n"; 
        $attrs = $product->attributes();                  // Attribute without prefix
        if(isset($attrs['num'])) echo "   num = " . $attrs['num'] . "\n";
    }
    else echo $product->getName() . " = " . $product ."\n";

    $attrs = $product->attributes('xml', true);           // if 2nd true, 1st is prefix
    if(isset($attrs['lang'])) echo "   lang = " . $attrs['lang'] . "\n";
}
```

result

```
Id = 123
Name = name english product
   lang = en
Description = desc xyz
   lang = en
Name = name german
   lang = de
Description = desc germa
   lang = de
Url = pic.jpg
   num = 1
Url = pic2.jpg
   num = 2
```

Comment: @Andreas Kleine i've updated the answer forattribute without prefix. But don't understant the first - about  the "de" Name

Comment: Hi & thanks a lot - I need the value of the <Name xml:lang="de">name german</Name>...so something like: if xml:lang = de $myname = name german

Comment: `if ($attrs['lang'] === 'de' && $product->getName() === 'Name' ) $myname = $product; `