# Not getting values of all attributes PHP XPATH

Tags: php, xpath

I am using PHP XML parser from link https://github.com/prewk/XmlStreamer
I get all data in  SimpleXMLElement Object. but it skip attribute values

sample XML

```
<xl:data>
  <details>
      <name xml:lang="en" type:"someVal"></name>
  </details>        
</xl:data>
```

It gives value of type in [@attributes]. but don't give value of xml:lang. How I can get values of all attributes of nodes, child nodes

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3996444/xmllang-parse-in-php/3996575 ?

Comment: @AndreaManzi in that case I have to apply XPath. I am trying to avoid it as XML is large. Can I get them in XML object. then I have other operations to perform on object